# jQuery Lightbox plugin to display image icons in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, path, lightbox

I have my loading, previous/next/close buttons for my lightbox in 'Content/Images/Lightbox`but am not quite sure how to point jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js to these files. It appears that no matter what I type in to try to point to the location in the lightbox script file, when I hover over the broken image links it ends up being`http://locahost:8080/Home/Project/../Content/Images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif`

This is when I go into the lightbox script file and change the locations to
 ../Content/Images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif which is relative to the javascript file (located in `Scripts/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js`).

Seems it just adds to the current location of the page that I'm on and `../` has no value since it just adds a literal string right to the end of the current URL. How can I fix this?

Comment: Normally I'd use @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif") but not quite sure how to add this razor syntax into the javascript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your prev/next/etc. buttons are in the '/Content/Images/Lightbox' folder, then the correct settings is (in file 'jquery.lightbox-0.5.js'):

```
// Configuration related to images
imageLoading:   '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',
imageBtnPrev:   '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',   
imageBtnNext:   '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif',   
imageBtnClose:  '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif',  
imageBlank:     '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-blank.gif',
```

The path is not relative to the lightbox's script file(jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js), it is relative to the root app path. Use '/' instead of '../etc.'. Path starting with "/" refers to the root directory and path starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts from there.

You may not want to change it in the main lightbox' script file, then set options in the view file:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({

        imageLoading: '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',
        imageBtnClose: '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-close.gif',
        imageBtnPrev: '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',
        imageBtnNext: '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-btn-next.gif',  
    });
});
```

If the button images are dynamic, you can use UrlHelper to create the paths in the veiw file e.g. `imageLoading: '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif")',`

Comment: Thank you... I swear I tried '/Content/images/Lightbox/lightbox-ico-loading.gif' and it didn't work... But it does now so thank you.